# https://sp.site.com/bu/dept -> https://dept.site.com

Tags: 2013, url, host-header, web-application-zones, host-named

I have a web application with a root site collection:

https://sp.site.com

I have further host named site collections like this:

https://sp.site.com/bu/dept1
https://sp.site.com/bu/dept2
https://sp.site.com/bu/dept3

Note: "bu" is just a host header managed path.

Then I have sites under these site collections like so:

https://sp.site.com/bu/dept1/site1
https://sp.site.com/bu/dept1/site2
https://sp.site.com/bu/dept2/site1
https://sp.site.com/bu/dept3/site1

Is it possible to add/change a site's URL from https://sp.site.com/bu/dept1/site1 to https://site1.site.com?

If not, is it possible to add/change a site collection's URL from https://sp.site.com/bu/dept1 to https://dept1.site.com?

I have tried to use `Set-SPSiteUrl` to add a URL for a site collection but I get an error message saying this can only be applied to the root site collection at https://sp.site.com.

Any other methods within or outside of SharePoint?

Comment: how you created the bu/dept1, as hostname site using powershell or managed path based site collection? i dont think you can change the url at subsite level but you can at site collection if it HNSC.

Comment: Hi Waqas, I mention in my question the site collections are host named site collections. "bu" is a host header. I also thought you could change HNSC URLs, but I think the limitation is when using `Set-SPSiteUrl` you can only change the URL to the root site collection, i.e at https://sp.site.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesm You can only change the url of the root site collection of HNSC. Here is what technet is describing;

> The [Set-SPSiteUrl](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219633.aspx) cmdlet only applies to the root site collection for
>   a host name that is, http://www.contoso.com. This cmdlet cannot be
>   directly run against a managed path site collection underneath the
>   root that is, http://www.contoso.com/sites/test.

But if you want to change it, then I am thinking of backup and restore option. Create new HSNC site collection using the new url, then take the backup of existing and restore it on newly created.

Comment: Any resources on how to restore a host named site collection backup?

Comment: For anyone wondering, I used this to help me: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/12/19/migrating-host-named-site-collections/